# How can use turkish lowercase ı in mysql

Tags: mysql, encoding, character-encoding

In mysql when a user tries to add a char entity with containing uppercase of turkish I it gives an error. I searched for the cause and I learned that turkish I is mixed with lower turkish ı and i when lowercasing. Is there any way to use lower turkish ı on mysql? My mysql server is utf8_general and collates with utf8_general_ci. Can windows-1254 may help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sum up, you should not use upper turkish I in any of your codes. It conficts with what just you said. Windows1254 sure helps with the issue of confliction.

Comment: I used windows1254 and it works. Thanks. Also windows1254 works with arabic letters

Answer (score 1):

I would not use the "general" collations in MySQL.  They are old and simple-minded.

What version of MySQL are you using?  For older versions, I would use utf8_unicode_520_ci or utf8_turkish_ci.

Because of the "dotless i" (`ı`), only the turkish colation works "correctly".  (OK, I am *not* an expert on how dotless i should compare.)

Looking at http://mysql.rjweb.org/utf8_collations.html , I see these lines of interest:

```
utf8_turkish_ci
   I=ı  Ħ=ħ  i=Ì=Í=Î=Ï=ì=í=î=ï=Ĩ=ĩ=Ī=ī=Ĭ=ĭ=Į=į=İ  ij=Ĳ=ĳ  iz     J=j=j́=Ĵ=ĵ jz
utf8_unicode_520_ci 
           I=i=Ì=Í=Î=Ï=ì=í=î=ï=Ĩ=ĩ=Ī=ī=Ĭ=ĭ=Į=į=İ  ij=Ĳ=ĳ  iz  ı  J=j=j́=Ĵ=ĵ jz
utf8_general_ci   
           I=i=Ì=Í=Î=Ï=ì=í=î=ï=Ĩ=ĩ=Ī=ī=Ĭ=ĭ=Į=į=İ=ı  ij    iz     J=j=Ĵ=ĵ   jz  j́
```

They tell me that the dotless *lowercase* i compares equal to dotless capital I *and* before H!  But for most other collations the lowercase dotless i compares *between* all I's and J's

Interestingly the *uppercase dotted* `İ` compares equal to most I's in most collations.

Meanwhile, the dotted and not, upper and lower I all compare equal in utf8_general_ci.

I don't happen to know what happens in windows-1254, but beware.

When you get to the new default (utf8mb4), there is yet another collation.  I don't know what to make of it.  It seems that certain accents collate after certain others:

```
utf8mb4_tr_0900_ai_ci 
    I=Ì=Í=Î=Ï=Ĩ=Ī=Ĭ=Į=ı  i=ì=í=î=ï=ĩ=ī=ĭ=į=İ   ij=Ĳ=ĳ   iz   J=j=j́=Ĵ=ĵ  jz
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I will consider all of these. I am using mysql 8.x. Also this case not happened my other mysql servers. So I guess this situation occurs in the last versions

Comment: If practical, do `SHOW CREATE TABLE` on both servers -- there may be a difference caused by the change to 8.0.  The _defaults_ have changed; I can't think off hand how that would have changed, say, a `COLLATION`.

Comment: I cannot access to the console right now. I will notify you as soon as when I get the logs. Thank you so much for your help